# One database .... spinning off multiple domains?

Tags: multi-domain

Let's say I am selling products, with each vertical having their own domain, and one central portal that sells all the products. Is this possible with one installation of Craft?

Only one admin panel would be needed.

Comment: Have you looked at http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-domain before?

Comment: @Maarten that's how I got to this question. Your comment is sending me into an infinite loop. :)